# Bash variable in curl header as user agent

Tags: bash, curl, user-agent, variable-expansion

I was trying to set the user agent dynamic from a bash variable. But it seems that is not that straight forward.

Since the header needs to be enclosed in  single quotes if the header value contains spaces, we cannot avoid the single quotes for user agent header, but if we do that the variable wont be evaluated and if we replace it with double quotes, the spaces in ua string will create a lot of mess.

The recommended way is to create all the header, data, cookie variable out side of curl command and use it in a single shot. But does that mean we never ever wont be able to set the user agent variable alone in the curl command?

The command I'm trying to use now is given below,

```
curl --proxy localhost:8000 -m 1 --retry 0  -i -s -S -b cookie.jar -c cookie.jar -X POST "https://myhost:51512/id?val=${id}" -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405'
```

to

```
linux_ua="Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/v1.0.0 Safari/537.1"
my_user_agent=$linux_ua
curl --proxy localhost:8000 -m 1 --retry 0  -i -s -S -b cookie.jar -c cookie.jar -X POST "https://myhost:51512/id?val=${id}" -H '${user_agent}'
```

Comment: What is not working here?

Answer (score 4):

The single quotes are simply shell syntax to prevent any sort of expansion inside the string; they are not part of the header itself. In this case, using double quotes would work just as well.

```
curl ... -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405"
```

Storing the user agent in a variable is trivial:

```
ua="user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405"
curl ... -H "$ua"
```

Here, you *must* use double quotes to expand the value of `$ua`; using `curl ... -H '$ua'` would send the literal 3-character string `$ua` as a header.

Answer (score 4):

You have encountered a particular problem with [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) in Bash, [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) has good examples on the subject.

You can run the following script to investigate the behavior.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# a script for the demonstration of word splitting

set -ex

url='localhost:8080/get' # docker run --rm -p 8080:80 kennethreitz/httpbin
user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1'

curl_opts_with_quote="--user-agent '${user_agent}'"
curl_opts_without_quote="--user-agent ${user_agent}"

curl -H 'Accept: application/json' $curl_opts_with_quote $url
curl -H 'Accept: application/json' $curl_opts_without_quote $url

curl_opts_array=(--user-agent "${user_agent}")

curl -H 'Accept: application/json' "${curl_opts_array[@]}" $url
```

Output

Notice that output lines start `+` and `User-Agent` returned from [httpbin](https://httpbin.org).

```
+ url=localhost:8080/get
+ user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1'
+ curl_opts_with_quote='--user-agent '\''Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1'\'''
+ curl_opts_without_quote='--user-agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1'
+ curl -H 'Accept: application/json' --user-agent ''\''Mozilla/5.0' '(Windows' NT '5.1;' 'rv:2.0.1)' Gecko/20100101 'Firefox/4.0.1'\''' localhost:8080/get
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: (Windows
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: NT
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 5.1;
curl: (3) Port number ended with '.'
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Gecko
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Firefox
{
  "args": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Host": "localhost:8080",
    "User-Agent": "'Mozilla/5.0"
  },
  "origin": "172.30.5.9",
  "url": "http://localhost:8080/get"
}
+ curl -H 'Accept: application/json' --user-agent Mozilla/5.0 '(Windows' NT '5.1;' 'rv:2.0.1)' Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1 localhost:8080/get
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: (Windows
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: NT
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 5.1;
curl: (3) Port number ended with '.'
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Gecko
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Firefox
{
  "args": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Host": "localhost:8080",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
  },
  "origin": "172.30.5.9",
  "url": "http://localhost:8080/get"
}
+ curl_opts_array=(--user-agent "${user_agent}")
+ curl -H 'Accept: application/json' --user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1' localhost:8080/get
{
  "args": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Host": "localhost:8080",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1"
  },
  "origin": "172.30.5.9",
  "url": "http://localhost:8080/get"
}
```